# serve huge static files with horizontal scale

Tags: database, file, distributed

I hope I can found a distributed filesystem which is easy to configure, easy to use, easy to learn.

Any one can help on this?

Answer (score 0):

As the details relating the usage is not mentioned and as much i can infer from the question, you must try MogileFS (Easy in setting it up and maintaining). Its is from the maker's of memcached and is used to server images etc.
Please refer to the below mentioned link for better explanation.

http://code.google.com/p/mogilefs/

[Lustre, Gluster or MogileFS?? for video storage, encoding and streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916902/lustre-gluster-or-mogilefs-for-video-storage-encoding-and-streaming)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you consider of using [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/). It has a lot of services and technologies to work with (Cassandra, HBase, etc). Quote from official site:

> Apache Hadoop is a framework that allows for the distributed processing of large data sets across clusters of computers using a simple programming model. It is designed to scale up from single servers to thousands of machines, each offering local computation and storage.

Basically, Hadoop is a large framework. You can use [Karmasphere studio](http://www.karmasphere.com/Products-Information/karmasphere-studio.html) with Hadoop. I suppose, with its help you can learn Hadoop much quicker get deeper into distibuted systems.

About HDFS: read the article "[GridGain and Hadoop](http://www.gridgain.com/blog/archives/gridgain-and-hadoop/)". Short quote from there:

> today HDFS is probably the most economical way to keep very large static data set of TB and PB scale in distributed file system for a long term storage

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3)](http://aws.amazon.com/s3).

It has (practically) unlimited storage, 100% uptime and tick most of the boxes needed for most situations. It isn't free, but is very cheap considering what you get.